# How to build nested array from flat Mongo DB document

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb

In my Mongo DB document, I used to have a nested array that I have converted to a nested document. So, for example, now my document looks like this:

```
{
    projects : {
        "id1" : {
            name : "project 1"
            parentProject : null
        },
        "id2" : {
            name : "project 2"
            parentProject : null
        },
        "id3" : {
            name : "sub project 1"
            parentProject : "id1"
        }.
    }
}
```

When I get this object in PHP, I have a array of size 3, each keyed by the project's ID:

```
array(
  'id1' => array('name' => 'project 1', 'parentProject' => null),
  'id2' => array('name' => 'project 2', 'parentProject' => null),
  'id3' => array('name' => 'project 3', 'parentProject' => 'id1')
)
```

I need to convert this to a hierarchical array, but I'm having trouble with the logic. Could someone help me convert it to something in the form:

```
array(
  array('ID' => 'id1', 'name' => 'project 1', 'subProjects' => 
      array('ID' => 'id3', 'name' => 'project 3', 'subProjects' => null)),
  array('ID' => 'id2', 'name' => 'project 2', 'subProjects' => null)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with the following solution:

```
public function createProjectHierarchy($projects, $parentId = null)
{
    $tree = array();

    foreach($projects as $projectKey => $project)
    {
        if($parentId == $project['parentProjectId'])
        {
            $project['subProjects'] = self::createProjectHierarchy($projects, $projectKey);
            $project['ID'] = $projectKey;
            unset($project['parentProjectId']);
            unset($projects[$projectKey]);

            array_push($tree, $project);
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

This returns the fully populated hierarchy the way I need it. Hopefully MongoDB will support multiple positional operators soon so that I can keep my data as arrays (and nested arrays) in the database.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be store it in the form you need it in your code. Therefore the "id3" object could just be an element inside of the "id1" project. Something like the following:

```
"id1": { 
  name:"project1", 
  subProjects:{ 
    "id3": { name:"project3" } 
  }
}
```

Another option would be to store each project as it's own document and use one of the "Model Tree Structures" data models in the MongoDB docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/